# What is wrong with this cron job?

Tags: cron, backup, digital-ocean, snapshot, cron-task

```
03 20 * * * do_snapshot --digital-ocean-access-token notreallymyaccesstoken96notreallymyaccesstoken3 --only 52713483 -k 3 -c -v
```

Running do_snapshot to take snapshot of my digital ocean droplet. I am able to do this manually via this command

```
do_snapshot --digital-ocean-access-token notreallymyaccesstoken96notreallymyaccesstoken3 --only 52713483 -k 3 -c -v
```

This works perfectly well and takes a snapshot of my droplet. However when i try to run cron job of the same - I fix time 2-3-5 mins ahead and save the cron job. But nothing happens. Been stuck on this for too long - I tried to read about cron job - and followed [this](https://ashout.com/automate-digital-ocean-droplet-snaphot/?unapproved=104762&moderation-hash=192adf0cfa67207172095ab22bf67287#comment-104762) tutorial word to word too

I am still not able to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the logs for what happens at the trigger time? `/var/log/cron` should contain some details.

Comment: Do you have the CRON_TZ directive set in any of your crontab configurations? If so, does it differ from the Timezone that your system is set to?

Answer (score 0):

Well no error in cron job script - it was difference in timezone as pointed out by @parttimeturtle. Also checking logs also helped, thank you both. This was really informative.